# Fetch the rows which have the Max value for a column - with duplicates

Tags: mysql

This answer from Bill Karwin to question 121387 worked perfectly for me..

"I see many people use subqueries or else vendor-specific features to do this, but I often do this kind of query without subqueries in the following way. It uses plain, standard SQL so it should work in any brand of RDBMS.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable AS t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable AS t2
    ON (t1.UserId = t2.UserId AND t1."Date" < t2."Date")
WHERE t2.UserId IS NULL;
```

In other words: fetch the row from t1 where no other row exists with the same UserId and a greater Date."

However, I also need to include in the result a column from a third table (imagine another table with UserId and UserPhoneNumber columns). It feels as if it should be straightforward but it's driving me nuts. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply join the third table after the LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT t1.*, t3.*
FROM mytable AS t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable AS t2
    ON (t1.UserId = t2.UserId AND t1."Date" < t2."Date")
JOIN myothertable AS t3 ON t1.UserId = t3.UserId
WHERE t2.UserId IS NULL;
```

Comment: Perfect! I tried something like this but when it didn't work (probably my typo) I gave up too quickly and tried something else. Thank you!